# Adding, Updating, and Deleting information from arcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, wpf, fields-attributes

I am new to ESRI and GIS. I am starting to get into using client data. I have created maps and put them to the server using arcMap and arcGIS for Server. I need to know how easily I can access these fields and if it is even possible to change them since the mapping data will change from time to time.

Attached is a screen shot of the fields in my map layer. I need to do this somewhat dynamically since each customer is different.

These are the fields for my layer (WVALVE):

[image]

I would like to be able to change what is contained in each field through the application and even take the information given in the maps and put it in my own database.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add, update, delete features you will first need to publish a "Feature Service", you can do this while publishing your service, by enabling "Feature Access".

Then depending on which programming language (Silverlight, Flex, iOS, Javascript, ... etc.) you're using, ESRI has a bunch of API's that allow you to access a Feature Service, to add, update and delete features.

Take a look at this link for [ESRI's Feature Layer implementation for Silverlight](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#//016600000015000000)

Now for the dynamic part, if you mean that your feature class will change, then you will need to republish your service to reflect the feature class changes in your service.

You can always show some kind of form dynamically, by querying the Feature Layer and finding the fields of that layer.

If you mean that the data and not the scheme will change, then that is no problem, as that will only add data to the service.